# SQLAlchemy reconnect to db

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I write daemon which use for DB SQLAlchemy. Database MySQL.
If daemon idle long time then connection is broken and I see errors.
Is it possible to make connect which cannot close while daemon is work or how to make reconnect to DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there's a option "pool_recycle" when creating engine, see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/engines.html?highlight=pool_recycle